# Exclude fields but still provide a default value

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to be able to hide a field from a form in the Django admin (I'm using Django 1.7), but still supply a default value (which is bound to the `request` as it is `request.user`).

Here are the contents of my `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import News

class NewsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'category', 'pub_date', 'visible',)
    list_filter = ('visible', 'enable_comments', 'category__topic', 'category__site', 'category',)
    search_fields = ['title']

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            self.exclude = ('author',)
        return super(NewsAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'author':
            kwargs['initial'] = request.user.id
        return super(NewsAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(News, NewsAdmin)
```

And here is what it does:

- As a superuser the `author` field correctly displays, preselecting the current user
- As any other staff member allowed to create a `News`, the `author` field is hidden, but when the form is submitted an exception is raised:

> IntegrityError at /admin/news/news/add/
>
> Column 'author_id' cannot be null

How can I hide the `author` field and still provide an `author_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found how to achieve what I wanted to do with a combination of two methods I have overriden.

Here the `get_form` method, now showing the `author` field as read-only instead of excluding it (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32212693/860283)). This is a change that is being made for editing purposes only (see `obj is not None`) to prevent an unwanted exception while editing someone else's news.

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    if not request.user.is_superuser and obj is not None:
        self.readonly_fields = ('author',)

    return super(NewsAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

And here is the `formfield_for_foreignkey` method. It simply filters the `QuerySet` to allow only one user.

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == 'author':
        kwargs['initial'] = request.user.id
        kwargs['queryset'] = User.objects.filter(pk=request.user.id)

    return super(NewsAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of excluding the field, you can set it to read only so that it will still show to the user, but they cannot change it:

```
self.readonly_fields = ('author',)
```

Comment: It only shows the label with no input in the form, thus the error is the same.

Comment: What should `author` be by default then? It sounds like you need to either prepopulate this field, set a default, or allow Null.

Comment: `author` needs to be the current user. This is why I can't set a default nor allow null. I don't understand why or how I should prepopulate it as it already is populated when displayed user a superuser account (because it's not excluded from the form).

Comment: It's just that the user currently adding the news must be the author of this news.